# TypeScript error on undefined value that is checked before

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a function that either adds an item to an array or updates an item to a given index if set.

I'm using **TypeScript** and I found a really strange behavior that I can't seem to understand.

Here is a [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2BBATllBPGAXhgG0ByAIxSzIF0AoegMwFcxhlwYB5AaQDE2HOOAAUSAKYBbAFwxoWBAHMANPDAATCQA8A-HLAspFCVgCUMAN70YtmKEiwmIEEXVbtMAISFibLUwIEho2dmG6PBQAVhIcAHQoEBBwSmCiJLRqCEiomDj4apakCB60cpJSMAC+FnIkcQ3ZyOjYuHhZUNK0ANz0VYys7JxgMAByfBgaGtxYAKoADhoonYJDImkVcgrKWZo6+jCGxqYW1mEO0PAQAJJ72gAiEoFgwW4lOt6+MP5PQRq953Al2crmIcBud0ez2CoTCtgi3GisSgCSSKTSGV2ORa+XaVmKdzK8E6lRqMDqDTiTVyrQKxK6vSqQA).

This simplified function is fine for TypeScript:

```
function OKAddOrUpdateFunction(item: string, index?: number) {
    const foo = index !== undefined
        ? Object.assign([], initialArray, { [index]: item }) : [...initialArray, item];
}
```

Now if I use a `const` and store either the `index` is defined or not so I can use it later on:

```
function NOKAddOrUpdateFunction(item: string, index?: number) {
    const isIndexDefined = index !== undefined;

    const foo = isIndexDefined
        ? Object.assign([], initialArray, { [index]: item }) : [...initialArray, item];
}
```

TypeScript throws an error pointing at the index inside the `Object.assign`:

```
(parameter) index: number | undefined
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.(2464)
```

And I can't understand why...

Comment: typescript cant 'store' type inferences like this, as in, it can't remember that you've stored the type inference information in the `isIndexDefined` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider such a case

```js
function NOKAddOrUpdateFunction(item: string, index?: number) {
    const isIndexDefined = index !== undefined || true; // always true

    const foo = isIndexDefined
        ? Object.assign([], initialArray, { [index]: item }) : [...initialArray, item];
}
```

Now even if index is `undefined`, `isIndexDefined` will be `true` so this code will run `Object.assign([], initialArray, { [index]: item })` and it will fail, because index of Array can not be undefined. (That is what TS is warning you about).

TS can not make an assumption about your variables before `if` statement.

In the first case, you check for undefined directly in if like `if (index !== undefined)` and in this case it is clear for TS that in `true` case your `index` is a number.

So possible solutions:

- check for undefined inside if statement (preferred)
- write [index as number], only if you are sure (if someone will change code before if, TS will not detect an error)